# How to parse EML files with attachments and inline images and convert to HTML

Tags: javascript, npm, spfx, mimekit, eml

we need to parse .EML files and show complete email with all inline images as well as all attachments on a webpage. i am able to extract HTML body using MimeKIT for .net. however we don't understand in what sequence can we differentiate between inline images and normal email attachments and render this all. Is there a library available that does that?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MimeKit.MimeMessage to Browser-Renderable HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31417916/mimekit-mimemessage-to-browser-renderable-html)

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer here:

Use this algorithm in this discussion on top of MIME kit and string encoding the images inline and it will give you completed email

[MimeKit.MimeMessage to Browser-Renderable HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31417916/mimekit-mimemessage-to-browser-renderable-html)